# Utilizing Joomla user information

Tags: codeigniter, joomla

I am planning to implement a web application using CodeIgniter. It will supplement a Joomla site of a client. When a user logs in at the Joomla site, he should be automatically logged in at the web application (CodeIgniter) also. How can this implemented?

Comment: in a broader perspective, you should find out how to make CodeIgniter talk to Joomla and vice versa. Accessing Joomla's internals would be the key to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since Joomla! 1.5 you can write [authentication plug-ins](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla_1.5) for that allow you to login to any web  application and have that login shared with Joomla! (as long as there was a matching plugin for the app).

The easiest solution is probably to use the [JFusion extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-bridges/3723) which does the bulk of the work and is well documented and supported. Then you can create a simple JFusion plugin to provide the integration you want.